# How are you in German

Tags: english-to-german, standard-german

Recently I have started studying German. I came across the phrase "Wie geht es Dir" which translates to How are you in English. I have read that Dir is used when an object is an indirect object. Could you tell me how "you" in this sentence is an indirect object?

Comment: Related [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/13781/1696).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept of "direct" and "indirect" objects doesn't apply in German. Instead, it has verb-specific valence frames which decide what arguments there can be and what case they take. The impersonal use of "gehen" occurs with a dative complement, but there isn't a generally valid construction that explains *all* uses of the dative.

Comment: This construction is an instance of a family of idiomatic constructions that use dative reflexivives to express, I guess, subjective impression... cf. _mir scheint_, _mir kommt vor_, _mir ist warm/kalt_, even _mir ist (nicht) erinnerlich_.